# jQuery: how to put a mouseover event on tag select generated by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, mouseover

In my page I have a select menu inside:

```
<div class="div1" style="float: left">
        <strong>Cerca Prodotto</strong>
        <br/><br/>
        <form class="form">
                <div><input type="text" id="tags" value=""></div>
                <div>
                <img class="btnaggiungi" src="http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/img/carrello.jpg" alt="Aggiungi" id="add_newProduct"/>
                </div>
        </form>

</div>
```

which is controlled and generated by the following jQuery:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/ajax/autocompletecibo",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                type : 'post',
                data:
                {
                    valore: request.term,
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, data ) {
          var selezione = data.item.label;
          $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: "http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/ajax/autocompletecibolista/valore/"+selezione,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){
                    $(".div2").html(msg);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...1");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now I need to add a mouse over event on every entry. I mean that when the user puts the mouse over an opion of the list, there are some other js code to be executed which, in the end, will show a map. How shall I add it?

**UPDATE**

This could be a solution:

```
<script>
 $(document).on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
  $(".div5").show();
 });

 $(document).on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
  $(".div5").hide();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the event to the static elements and then delegate it to your dynamically generated ones. I mean if `<div class="div1">` is the container for your dynamically generated HTML, you have to do something like this:

```
$('.div1').on('mouseover','.div2 .dynamicallyGeneratedList',function(){
    console.log('do something');
})
```

Comment: it does not work for me...maybe I have not understood how it works

Answer (score 1):

Your question is'nt quite entirely. How does your data response look like? Maybe does this help you.

```js
$(data).each(function() {
  var $li = $("<li>"+data+"</li>");
  $li.bind("mouseover", showMap);
  $("ul").append($li);      
});

function showMap() {
  // show map
}
```

Comment: the data is an array got with fetchAll() from php

Comment: So you want to append your result items to a `<ul>` like a `<li>`?

Comment: yes, when I start typing something I get a `<ul><li>...<li></ul>`. I have tried with

Comment: `$('li[id^="ui-id-"]').on("mouseover",function() {
   $("div[id=single_position]").show();
 })`

Comment: Could this work? See updated answer. Or is the response date including html markup?